# Neo4j: Create paths/subgraph from APOC virtual relationships for streaming to Gephi

Tags: neo4j, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I have a Neo4j database comprising `Film` and `Person` nodes connected by `ACTED_IN` relationships. Using APOC, I've managed to create a set of virtual `ACTED_WITH` relationships directly between `Person` nodes reflecting the fact that they're indirectly related through a `Film` in which they both appeared:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b:Person)
WITH a, b
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a, 'ACTED_WITH', {}, b) YIELD rel
RETURN a, rel, b
```

This seems to capture the indirect relationship I'm looking for. Now I want to stream the results of this to Gephi for visualisation. But the relevant APOC function takes a `paths` argument. So this works:

```
MATCH path = ()-[:ACTED_IN]->()
WITH collect(path) AS paths
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace0', paths) YIELD nodes, relationships, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time
```

How can I create a set of paths from the virtual relationships yielded in the first code block for passing to Gephi as in the second? (Or is there a better way to deal with this kind of case?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the `apoc.gephi.add` procedure can be instanceof: Node, Relationship, Path, Iterable, Map, Iterator, Object.

So it should work like this:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b:Person) WHERE ID(a) > ID(b) 
WITH DISTINCT a, b
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a, 'ACTED_WITH', {}, b) YIELD rel AS rel1
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(b, 'ACTED_WITH', {}, a) YIELD rel AS rel2
WITH collect(rel1) + collect(rel2) + collect(a) + collect(b) AS data
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace0', data) YIELD nodes, relationships, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time
```

**Update**: If you need weights, then you can simply aggregate by the films:

```
MATCH (a:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(M:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(b:Person) WHERE ID(a) > ID(b) 
WITH a, b, 
     count(M) as vWeight
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(a, 'ACTED_WITH', {weight: vWeight}, b) YIELD rel AS rel1
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(b, 'ACTED_WITH', {weight: vWeight}, a) YIELD rel AS rel2
WITH collect(rel1) + collect(rel2) + collect(a) + collect(b) AS data
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null, 'workspace0', data) YIELD nodes, relationships, time
RETURN nodes, relationships, time
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Kind of an extension to my original question, but is there a good way to collapse parallel relationships between nodes together? (What I mean is duplicated connections between nodes created when two actors appear in more than one film together.)

Comment: @rjww Depends on your goals. In my opinion, there must be one relationship with the property by the number of common films.

Comment: Yes, ideally there would be a single virtual relationship (or reciprocal pair, I guess, given that Neo4j graphs are directed) between co-appearing actors with a weight property that is a count of the number of films in which they appear together. The end goal is to get something like that into Gephi so that I can create some exploratory visualisations with different measures of centrality, etc.

Comment: @rjww For weights use the aggregation function `count`. See the addition to the answer.

Comment: What is the possible solution for merging the duplicate virtual relationship between two nodes?

Comment: @daudichya Can you clarify your question with an example?

Comment: @stdob please go through below the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465211/how-to-group-or-merge-virtual-relationship-created-using-apoc-create-vrelationsh
Thanks for your interest!